# Postgres query is not using index

Tags: postgresql

I am facing very strange behavior of postgres query. I am having a table "p_MyTable" which is a partition of another table. "p_MyTable" has around 600 million records and has index ,

```
CREATE INDEX idx_p_MyTable_id ON MySchema.p_MyTable USING btree(IndColumn);
```

When I execute the below query it runs in no time and gives result very fast. This is the query and explain plan.

```
    explain select max(IndColumn) from MySchema.p_MyTable ms where ent_attr_97='ABC' and ent_attr_96='EFG' and ent_attr_98='HIJ'
and ent_date_2::date <= '2017-06-01 00:00:00'::date

"Result  (cost=4.85..4.86 rows=1 width=0)"
"  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)"
"    ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..4.85 rows=1 width=8)"
"          ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_p_MyTable_id on p_MyTable ms  (cost=0.57..727648341.49 rows=169996075 width=8)"
"                Index Cond: (IndColumn IS NOT NULL)"
"                Filter: ((ent_attr_97 = 'ABC'::text) AND (ent_attr_96 = 'EFG'::text) AND (ent_attr_98 = 'HIJ'::text) AND ((ent_date_2)::date <= '2017-06-01'::date))"
```

It works for aggregate function "min" as well in same way. But when I try for other functions , the explain plan changes and query does not execute in many minutes.

```
    explain select count(IndColumn) from MySchema.p_MyTable ms where ent_attr_97='ABC' and ent_attr_96='EFG' and ent_attr_98='HIJ'
and ent_date_2::date <= '2017-06-01 00:00:00'::date

"Aggregate  (cost=53319339.50..53319339.51 rows=1 width=8)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on p_MyTable ms  (cost=11209851.27..52894349.31 rows=169996075 width=8)"
"        Recheck Cond: (ent_attr_96 = 'EFG'::text)"
"        Filter: ((ent_attr_97 = 'ABC'::text) AND (ent_attr_98 = 'HIJ'::text) AND ((ent_date_2)::date <= '2017-06-01'::date))"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on p_MyTable_comp  (cost=0.00..11167352.25 rows=509988224 width=0)"
"              Index Cond: (ent_attr_96 = 'EFG'::text)"

explain select distinct (IndColumn) from MySchema.p_MyTable ms where ent_attr_97='ABC' and ent_attr_96='EFG' and ent_attr_98='HIJ'
and ent_date_2::date <= '2017-06-01 00:00:00'::date

"HashAggregate  (cost=53319339.50..53319339.71 rows=21 width=8)"
"  Group Key: IndColumn"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on p_MyTable ms  (cost=11209851.27..52894349.31 rows=169996075 width=8)"
"        Recheck Cond: (ent_attr_96 = 'EFG'::text)"
"        Filter: ((ent_attr_97 = 'ABC'::text) AND (ent_attr_98 = 'HIJ'::text) AND ((ent_date_2)::date <= '2017-06-01'::date))"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on p_MyTable_comp  (cost=0.00..11167352.25 rows=509988224 width=0)"
"              Index Cond: (ent_attr_96 = 'EFG'::text)"

explain select avg (IndColumn) from MySchema.p_MyTable ms where ent_attr_97='ABC' and ent_attr_96='EFG' and ent_attr_98='HIJ'
and ent_date_2::date <= '2017-06-01 00:00:00'::date

"Aggregate  (cost=53319339.50..53319339.51 rows=1 width=8)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on p_MyTable ms  (cost=11209851.27..52894349.31 rows=169996075 width=8)"
"        Recheck Cond: (ent_attr_96 = 'EFG'::text)"
"        Filter: ((ent_attr_97 = 'ABC'::text) AND (ent_attr_98 = 'HIJ'::text) AND ((ent_date_2)::date <= '2017-06-01'::date))"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on p_MyTable_comp  (cost=0.00..11167352.25 rows=509988224 width=0)"
"              Index Cond: (ent_attr_96 = 'EFG'::text)"
```

Please explain me, why the explain changes completely as I think if max/min are using index properly then it should work for other functions as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have verified , table is vacuumed and analyzed recently.

Answer (score 0):

indexes are (mostly) used for either "where" conditions, or to help sorting ("order by").
(well indexes can be used for lots of other things, but for this case it will help to limit it to those cases)

The "max(IndColumn)" is misleading, because the query is rewritten as:

```
select IndColumn
from MySchema.p_MyTable ms 
where ent_attr_97='ABC' and ent_attr_96='EFG' and ent_attr_98='HIJ'
and ent_date_2::date <= '2017-06-01 00:00:00'::date
AND IndColumn is not null 
ORDER by IndColumn desc 
LIMIT 1
```

So the index is used for "AND IndColumn is not null ORDER by IndColumn desc".

For your other queries you would need indexes for the columns in "where",
Something like

```
CREATE INDEX idx_p_foo ON MySchema.p_MyTable USING btree(ent_attr_96, ent_attr_97, ent_attr_98);
```

might help.
Assuming that you have many queries that use those 3 columns.

You can also add the date. Though I am not sure this will help much, since it only is an end date, with no begin given.
So not sure if the query planer will use the date in the index. And if it does, the question is how many rows are filtered by the date, is it worth increasing the index size?